# Interpret an integer as a pointer to a dynamic string, from a dynamic block pointed to by a pointer to pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, dynamic, casting

Am I making sense? This is what I'm trying to do:

```
unsigned int *a = 0;
unsigned int **b = &a;
// b -> a -> null

*b = (unsigned int*)malloc(12);
// b -> a -> [xxxx|xxxx|xxxx]

*(*b+1) = (unsigned int)malloc(sizeof("come on!"));
// b -> a -> [xxxx|xxxx|xxxx]
//                 v
//                [xxxxxxxxx]

strcpy((char*)*(*b+1),"come on!");  // FAILS! why?
```

I'm not sure what else I can describe.

Comment: Why are you assuming that pointers and integers are always 4 bytes?

Comment: haha Oh man, I forgot I'm running a 64-bit system. Yeah, need 8 bytes for pointers. Whoops! Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the figures? They're just simplified visualizations.

Comment: I wish I could set Blagovest Buyukliev's initial comment as the accepted answer. That's all I really needed (as embarrassing as that is). The other answers do have some useful information though. Thanks again! (Apparently I don't have enough reputation to at least upvote them...) And yes, I know my implementation seems really wonky. I was doing some tests which ended up this way, and although I don't really need it for anything, I was just super confused as to why it wasn't working.

Comment: P.S. Bonus points to Nick for the awesome avatar!

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on a 32-bit environment. However @Blagovest Buyukliev is right in that you shouldn't make assumptions about the size of pointers (even if it seems to work). You would be better off changing those *unsigned int*'s for *char**´s. See below a slightly modified version:

```
char* *a = 0;
char* **b = &a;
// b -> a -> null

*b = malloc(12);
// b -> a -> [xxxx|xxxx|xxxx]

*((*b)+1) = malloc(sizeof("come on!"));
// b -> a -> [xxxx|xxxx|xxxx]
//                 v
//                [xxxxxxxxx]

strcpy(*((*b)+1),"come on!");  // FAILS! why?

printf("%s", a[1]);
```

That said, even though it works and it might be a good way of learning about pointers and memory, you should check language usage on the matter.
I added a *printf()* to see the string.

Comment: Not only that, it's undefined behaviour. Even on a 32 bit system, the size of an `unsigned int` is not guaranteed to be 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the real intent of this program, but considering the visualizations, I think you got it wrong and I would rewrite it as follows:

```
// why do you need a at all? b can be initialised to NULL without a second variable
// unsigned int *a = NULL;
unsigned int **b = NULL;

// you are allocating 3 pointers here
b = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int *) * 3);
// b -> [xxxx|xxxx|xxxx]

// the second pointer is made to point to newly allocated memory
*(b + 1) = malloc(sizeof("come on!"));
// b -> [xxxx|xxxx|xxxx]
//            v
//           [xxxxxxxxx]

strcpy((char *) *(b + 1), "come on!");
```

Also note the use of `sizeof(unsigned int *)` to determine the size of a pointer instead of relying on hardcoded, unreliable assumptions.